# In a binary vector $ x \in \{0,1\}^{k}$ what does the $^{k}$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In a binary vector $ x \in \{0,1\}^{k}$ what does the $^{k}$ mean? I understand that $\in$ means 'is a possible outcome' or 'in' so x can be 0 or 1, but I'm not sure what the $^{k}$ means.

Comment: See [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as points in $\mathbb R^k$ consist of ordered tuples of $k$ real numbers, so points in $\left\{0,1\right\}^k$ consist of ordered tuples of $k$ "bits".

The typical point $x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k)$, where each $x_i\in\left\{0,1\right\}$ (that is, each $x_i$ is $0$ or $1$).

Comment: So it's just saying there are k elements in each vector, with each element being 0 or 1? so if k = 3, then x could be {000,001,010,100,011,110,101,111}?

Comment: @larrysummersstatistics: Correct. The usual notation would be (0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), etc. but you have the idea.